# celery beat scheduler not scheduling tasks as expected using crontab

Tags: python-3.x, cron, celery, celerybeat

Celery beat is not scheduling tasks as expected using crontab. It schedules at random time. Sometimes it schedules every one minute once. Sometimes every two minutes once, etc.
There is no relation between configured time  `"schedule": crontab(hour='*/1')` and the time at which task is  getting sent to worker!

No clue what's wrong here.

Here is my celery_test.py :

```
from kombu import Queue, Exchange
from celery import Celery, shared_task, group, chord
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('celery_demo',
             broker='amqp://abcduser:abcdpassword@localhost/abcd_vhost',
             backend='rpc://',
             include=['celery_demo.tasks'])

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "trigger-call_publisher": {
        "task": "celery_demo.tasks.call_publisher",
        "schedule": crontab(hour='*/1')
```

The below is my tasks.py :

```
import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from celery_demo.celery_test import app

@app.task
def call_publisher():
    print("Say Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_publisher.delay()

    }
}
```

The below is one such output where the tasks are sent every minute once:

[image]

Comment: I am confused - the log shows clearly that the beat have sent the task every minute. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I have set it to run every one hour ```"schedule": crontab(hour='*/1')```. But it is running every one minute. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that dor making it run every hour you either use minute:

```
crontab(minute='*/60')
```

or hour + minute:

```
crontab(minute=0, hour='*/1')
```

Comment: this time there is little improvement in the scheduling. But still it did not schedule the task every one hour once as configured.

Comment: ```[2020-10-19 06:13:09,387: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2020-10-19 06:13:09,442: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task trigger-call_publisher (celery_demo.tasks.call_publisher)
[2020-10-19 07:00:00,001: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task trigger-call_publisher (celery_demo.tasks.call_publisher)```                                                                          Here the first task is sent at ```[2020-10-19 06:13:09,442``` and the second one is at ```[2020-10-19 07:00:00,001```. So there is around 46 minutes gap between two tasks.

Comment: @owgitt is 06:13 the time that you restart your beat? what about the next task after 07:00? is it at 08:00?

Comment: 06:13 the time that you restart your beat - YES. And that time itself the first task was sent.  Next task(second one)  is sent at 7:00.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The "on start" task shouldn't run, I guess it related to some configuration you set. I am asking about the 3rd one, is it at 08:00? if so, the problem was only at beat restart

Comment: Yes. Third one started at 08:00. So there is one hour gap between second and third task scheduling. As you told it looks the problem was only at beat restart !

Comment: @owgitt right. If that worked for you I appreciate if you accept this answer :)